# Ruby convert string to method name

Tags: ruby, methods

I have two methods defined in my ruby file.

```
def is_mandatory(string)
      puts xyz
end
def is_alphabets(string)
      puts abc 
end
```

An array containing the names of the methods.

```
    methods = ["is_mandatory", "is_alphabets"]
```

When I do the following

```
    methods.each do |method| puts method.concat("(\"abc\")") end
```

It just displays,  is_mandatory("abc") is_alphabets("abc") rather than actually calling the method.

How can i convert the string to method name? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!!

Comment: On a side note, the Ruby way of doing is_* methods is by using a question mark rather than the prefix "is", i.e. `mandatory?` and `alphabets?`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Best way is probably:

```
methods.each { |methodName| send(methodName, 'abc') }
```

See [Object#send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send)

Comment: If these methods belong to some class?

Comment: Then you want something like: `obj = OwningClass.new; methods.each { |meth| obj.send(meth, 'abc') }`

Comment: or if we're talking about class methods, then `methods.each{ |method| Class.send(meth, argument) }`

Answer (score 15):

Try using "send".

```
methods.each do |method| 
  self.send(method, "abc")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

All previous solutions with `send` are fine but it is recommended to use [public_send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send) instead (otherwise you can be calling private methods).

Example:

```
'string'.public_send(:size)
=> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add hash to send parameters to the method.

```
send("method_name", "abc", {add more parameters in this hash})
```