# String to method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cant seem to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036446/ruby-convert-string-to-method-name) but maybe it's different from what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a string, that string can be different at time, I need to convert that string into a defined method name:

```
action = "get_name"

# The method
def get_name
  puts "James"
end

# Calling the method
action # => undefined method `action' for main:Object
```

`action` can be any of my defined methods and the names are in a string format. Could I say `action.to_method`, you get what I mean ;)

I dont think I could say `action.to_sym`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
method(action).call
```

or

```
public_send(action)
```

Example:

```
method(action).call
#=> James
public_send(action)
#=> James
```

Be aware, though, that ***none*** of the above cares about the context, where was method originally defined, so both will call it in the context of the current object.

Comment: Hi, would that work even if I have params ie: `action(a,b)`

Comment: @Sylar no, in that case it will not work. because, for example, with `public_send` it sould look like `public_send(action, a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are arguments.

Comment: `public_send()` is best. Thank you!

Comment: @Sylar with such case `eval` would do: `eval("action(1,2)")`, where `1` and `2` are actual arguments. But as we all know, `eval` is evil, ***especially*** when you are evaluating something from incoming params, so don't even think about it!)

Comment: So what's the safest? `public_send`?

Comment: @Sylar absolutely, `public_send` does care even about the scope of the defined method, so if you try to call `private` method with `public_send` it will fail, whereas with `send` it will call it anyway. So for clean interface `public_send` is safest you can get.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that `public_send` is still dangerous with parameters provided by the user, because `send` is itself a public method. So if the user can control additional parameters, they can call pretty much any method on the object. And since any descendant of `Object` has dangerous private methods like `eval` and `exit!` by default, you can get into a lot of trouble. The only safe thing to do with user-provided parameters is to compare them against a list of explicitly allowed methods.

Comment: @Sylar yea, what Max says, white-list of allowed methods is really the only safe way to "let" user do that. Thx Max for comment!

Comment: @Max Thanks. No user calls any method, only functions.